# How can I ignore special characters, like an apostrophe?

Tags: javascript, cordova, appery.io

When I am testing my app, it seems that it gets confused with an " ' " (apostrophe). I think that it thinks that I am ending a string but I am not. The string just contains a special character.

This is what I have tried so far but it didn't work:

```
var str = Apperyio("books_selectmenu").val();

return str.replace(/([ #;?&,.+*~:"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'1');
```

If you are familiar with PhoneGap and Appery.io, this might make more sense. In the mapping section, I am listing strings from a database to a select menu. If those strings contain an apostrophe, I can an error back and the app doesn't work normally.

How can I get it to think of the apostrophe as a regular character?

Comment: So where is this quote character? The problem you describe (in the mapping section) doesn't seem to be in the question.

Comment: there's no apostrophe/single quote in your regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to pinpoint the problem actually, the [.val() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) guarantees a safe return value (apparently with the exception of the carriage return character)

It is more probable the problem comes from another part of the code, but, as a general solution, you can try the following:

```
var str = encodeURI(Apperyio("books_selectmenu").val());
```

[encodeURI replaces all characters [...] with the appropriate UTF-8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Then, when you're ready to use/output the string:

```
var decoded = decodeURI(str);
```